# MySQL group replication between two servers behind NAT

Tags: mysql, replication

does MySQL group replication should work if I have a server behind NAT?

I have a Hetzner CX server which has eth0 interface with addr 172.31.1.100. 
Hetzner provides 1:1 NAT for this server and public IP (ex.: 123.123.123.101).

I tried to setup group replication with the following IP-related settings:

```
loose-group_replication_local_address = "172.31.1.100:33061"
loose-group_replication_ip_whitelist = "172.31.1.100,123.123.123.101,123.123.123.102"
loose-group_replication_group_seeds = "123.123.123.101:33061,123.123.123.102:33061"
```

and it doesn't work, due to error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
[ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timeout on wait for view after joining group'
```

Replication user hostname defined as '%'.

When I tried to use the same configuration for servers without NAT - it works without any issues.

Please advice how to fix the problem or maybe MySQL doesn't support such situation.

Comment: Just checking, are you trying to set up group replication across the Internet? According to the documentation, MySQL group replication "is designed to be deployed in a cluster environment where server instances are very close to each other".

Comment: Two instances are in the same datacenter. The latency is very low. But they can't access each other by private network like on AWS.

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar issue, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837554/mysql-group-replication-timeout-while-waiting-for-the-group-communication-engin Were you able to find a solution to this issue?